# Custom Data Generator for Keras LSTM with TimeSeriesGenerator

Tags: python, keras, lstm

So I'm trying to use Keras' [fit_generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) with a custom data generator to feed into an LSTM network.

## What works

To illustrate the problem, I have created a toy example trying to predict the next number in a simple ascending sequence, and I use the Keras [TimeseriesGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#timeseriesgenerator) to create a Sequence instance:

```
WINDOW_LENGTH = 4
data = np.arange(0,100).reshape(-1,1)
data_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(data, data, length=WINDOW_LENGTH,
                               sampling_rate=1, batch_size=1)
```

I use a simple LSTM network:

```
data_dim = 1
input1 = Input(shape=(WINDOW_LENGTH, data_dim))
lstm1 = LSTM(100)(input1)
hidden = Dense(20, activation='relu')(lstm1)
output = Dense(data_dim, activation='linear')(hidden)

model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and train it using the `fit_generator` function:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=data_gen,
                    steps_per_epoch=32,
                    epochs=10)
```

And this trains perfectly, and the model makes predictions as expected.

## The problem

Now the problem is, in my non-toy situation I want to process the data coming out from the TimeseriesGenerator before feeding the data into the `fit_generator`. As a step towards this, I create a generator function which just wraps the TimeseriesGenerator used previously.

```
def get_generator(data, targets, window_length = 5, batch_size = 32):
    while True:
        data_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(data, targets, length=window_length, 
                                       sampling_rate=1, batch_size=batch_size)
        for i in range(len(data_gen)):
            x, y = data_gen[i]
            yield x, y

data_gen_custom = get_generator(data, data,
                                window_length=WINDOW_LENGTH, batch_size=1)
```

But now the strange thing is that when I train the model as before, but using this generator as the input,

```
model.fit_generator(generator=data_gen_custom,
                    steps_per_epoch=32,
                    epochs=10)
```

There is no error but the training error is all over the place (jumping up and down instead of consistently going down like it did with the other approach), and the model doesn't learn to make good predictions.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong with my custom generator approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It could be because the object type is changed from `Sequence` which is what a `TimeseriesGenerator` is to a generic generator. The `fit_generator` function treats these differently. A cleaner solution would be to inherit the class and override the processing bit:

```
class CustomGen(TimeseriesGenerator):
  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    x, y = super()[idx]
    # do processing here
    return x, y
```

And use this class like before as the rest of internal logic will remain the same.

Comment: Hey @nuric, thanks so much for the response! That actually works perfectly for the toy example I described, but in fact my real problem deals with something slightly different (my bad for not giving the actual situation). I want to read two separate streams of data, hence using two TimeseriesGenerators, and that's why I wanted to have a custom generator to read and merge them both. Using this approach of inheriting the class I can't think of how I could read from two streams at once. Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: You could write your own [sequence class](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) and use two timeseries inside it to generate two separate streams and combine it into a one as single Sequence.

Comment: Perfect! I did as you said, basically duplicated the TimeseriesGenerator source code but allowing for two data inputs, and that does what I want. Thank you very much! I'll mark this answer as accepted as it does answer my original question.

Comment: @JunShernChan I am trying to solve the same problem. Could you illustrate more details how you resolved it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I personally had a problem with the code by nuric. For some reason I had the error saying super not being subscriptable. Here is my possible fix. Let me known if this could possibly work?

```py
class CustomGen(TimeseriesGenerator):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        x,y = super().__getitem__(idx)
        return x, y
```