# Join two class objects - Python

Tags: python, generator

I have two generators:

```
generator1 = CustomGen(X1,X1, length=W, stride = 1,sampling_rate=1, batch_size=bt_size)
generator2 = CustomGen(X2,X2, length=W, stride = 1,sampling_rate=1, batch_size=bt_size)
```

that are created using the function adopted from [Custom Data Generator for Keras LSTM with TimeSeriesGenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322660/custom-data-generator-for-keras-lstm-with-timeseriesgenerator):

```
class CustomGen(TimeseriesGenerator):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        x, y = super().__getitem__(idx)
        # do processing here
        return x, x
```

Each object has **m** number of batches.  I would like to join these two objects into one having a total of **2m** batches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.chain` could be your friend here:

```
generator = itertools.chain(generator1, generator2)
```

It will return all elements from `generator1`, followed with elements from `generator2`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The output of chain is not of the same type of generator1 (or generator2) type. Is there an althenative way as such the object type is retained.